# How to pass a state from a child to a parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i have a child component and a parent component. In the child component there is a state. The state has to toggle between classNames in the parent component. How can i do that?

```html
export function Parent({ children, darkMode }) {
  return (
    <div className={cx(styles.component, darkMode && styles.darkMode)}>
      { children }
    </div>
  )
}

export function Child() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <header>
      <div className={styles.component}>
        <div className={styles.content}>
          <button onClick={colorSwith} className={styles.toggle}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
  function colorSwith() {
    setDarkMode(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of putting state in children, You can set state in the parent, and pass a change state function down to the children, so children can modify parent state by calling function passed by the parent.

Comment: [lift](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) your state on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

## With state it's 1 directional

It's not possible to pass state up the tree. In the solution below you might need to bind the function. You can mod props of children via the clone element React method.

```
export function Parent({ children, darkMode }) {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <div className={cx(styles.component, darkMode && styles.darkMode)}>
      {React.cloneElement(children, { setDarkMode })}
    </div>
  )
}

export function Child(props) {
  return (
    <header>
      <div className={styles.component}>
        <div className={styles.content}>
          <button onClick={colorSwith} className={styles.toggle}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
  function colorSwith() {
    props.setDarkMode(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use the context api

You can also use the context api to access state anywhere in the tree. This way any component that has access to the context will rerender on change and data is passable and changable to any point in the tree.

Check out this example from the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

```
const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: "#000000",
    background: "#eeeeee"
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: "#ffffff",
    background: "#222222"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.light);

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={themes.dark}>
      <Toolbar />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function ThemedButton() {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <button style={{ background: theme.background, color: theme.foreground }}>
      I am styled by theme context!
    </button>
  );
} 

See how the context is set on the `App` level with a `Provider` and then changed in the `ThemeButton` with the `useContext` hook. This is a simple use case that seems simmilar to yours.
```

Comment: And how does this looks like in my case?